# Equal heights of elements and align to bottom

Tags: html, css, height

how do I set the equal height of each content and inline `span` equally after the content?

**CSS**

```
.box {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box-image {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box, .box-image, .box-text {
    transition: opacity 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s, background-color 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s, background-color 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
}


.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.box-text {
    padding-top: .7em;
    padding-bottom: 1.4em;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: .9em;
}

.box-text  p {
        margin-bottom: 1.9em;
        font-size:14px;
}

.box-text h3 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #272627;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}

.totalviewpost, .catname a, .timeago {
    font-size: 10px !important;
    color: #272627;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
     text-shadow: none;
}

.totalviewpost:before {
    content: '\f06e';
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.timeago:before {
    content: '\f017';
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.catname:before {
    content: '\f03a';
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: #272627 !important; 
}
```

**Html**

```
    <div class="box has-hover has-hover box-text-bottom" >
                     <div class="box-image" >
                        <div class="" >
                           <a onClick="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" data-postid="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                           <img src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" width="277" height="277"> 
                           </a>                                      
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <!-- box-image -->
                     <div class="box-text" >
                        <div class="box-text-inner">
                           <h3 style="text-align: left;"><a onClick="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" data-postid="<?php echo get_the_ID();?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
                           <p class="content" style="text-align: left;"><?php 
                              $trimmed = wp_filter_nohtml_kses( wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 20, '....') );

                              echo $trimmed;        
                               ?></p>
                               <div>
                              <span class="totalviewpost"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?>  &nbsp;| &nbsp; </span>
                              <span class="timeago"><?php echo get_the_date( 'Y-m-d' ); ?> &nbsp; | &nbsp;</span> 
                              <span class="catname"><?php $category = get_the_category(); ?>
<a  href="<?php echo get_category_link($category[0]->cat_ID); ?> ">
<?php echo $category[0]->cat_name; ?> </a></span></div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- box-text-inner -->
                     </div>
                     <!-- box-text -->
                  </div>
```

Screen Shot of the problem
[image]

Comment: should I paste CSS also?

Comment: @Paulie_D CSS and full code updated kindly check it

Comment: @Paulie_D how do I set equally span?

Comment: Nevermind, I've added an answer to explain how this can be managed.

Comment: set that div absolute and give padding bottom to parent div, may be it's solution to your issue

Answer (score -1):

There is **no** CSS method for aligning elements / equalising heights *that do not share a parent*.

What you *can* do, in this instance is push the last div to the bottom of each column.

Flexbox can do that. You will have to adapt the code in the example below to your situation but that is the principle.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 0 33%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: .5em;
}

.img-wrap {
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-wrap"> <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt=""></div>
    <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed ratione accusantium iure laudantium vero doloribus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, cumque.</p>
    <footer>My footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-wrap"> <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt=""></div>
    <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed ratione accusantium iure laudantium vero doloribus.</p>
    <footer>My footer</footer>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="img-wrap"> <img src="http://www.fillmurray.com/300/200" alt=""></div>
    <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <footer>My footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```